# concat rows after doing multiple table joins in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, split, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I have created a minimal example sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nrPMDTKD0uHbWkAu-3c9DUoxBptB13lScOe8XI8zxF4/edit?usp=sharing.

I will explain:

- `issues and recommendations` is a list of issues with their recommendations

  - Each issue has 1+ recommendation in one cell; for example: `B2` has `alpha` and `charlie`
  - A recommendation could apply to multiple issues; for example: recommendation `alpha` applies to issue `1`, `2`, and `5`
- `issues and recommendations split` - I took the data in `issues and recommendations` and split it so each recommendation was in one line
- `recommendations` is a unique list of just the recommendations. And I assigned each recommendation a unique ID.
- `recommendation plans` - each recommendation has 1+ plan on this sheet. Each plan is on it's own line.

Now, in `issues and recommendations`.`plans` (column `C`) I want an `ARRAYFORMULA` or something that will find all of the `recommendation plans`.`plans` (column `C`) for the recommendations in `issues and recommendations`.`recommendation` (column `B`), and combine them into one cell.

In the last column of `issues and recommendations` I put an example column with the expected output. Using issue `1` as an example:

- two recommendations:

  - `alpha` has `recommendations ID` of `1` that has these plans:

    - `do this`
    - `do that`
  - `charlie` has `recommendation ID` of `1` that has these plans:

    - `do 001`
    - `do 002`
    - `do bingo`
- so if you combine them you get:

  ```
  - do this
  - do that
  - do 001
  - do 002
  - do bingo
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(B2:B, CHAR(10)), 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY({"- "&'recommendation plans'!B2:B&"♦", 
 "- "&'recommendation plans'!C2:C&"♥♥", ROW('recommendation plans'!A2:A)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 <> '- ♦' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9))), 
 "♦")), 2, 0))),,9^9))), "♥♥$", ), "♥ -", "♥-"), "♥", CHAR(10)))
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            REGEXREPLACE(
                TRIM(
                    FLATTEN(
                        QUERY(
                            TRANSPOSE(
                                IFERROR(
                                    VLOOKUP(
                                        SPLIT(
                                            B2:B,
                                            CHAR(10)
                                        ),
                                        TRIM(
                                            SPLIT(
                                                FLATTEN(
                                                    TRIM(
                                                        QUERY(
                                                            QUERY(
                                                                {
                                                                    "- " & 'recommendation plans'!B2:B & "♦",
                                                                    "- " & 'recommendation plans'!C2:C & "♥♥",
                                                                    ROW('recommendation plans'!A2:A)
                                                                },
                                                                "select max(Col2) where Col1 <> '- ♦' group by Col3 pivot Col1"
                                                            ),
                                                            ,
                                                            9^9
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                ),
                                                "♦"
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        2,
                                        0
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            ,
                            9^9
                        )
                    )
                ),
                "♥♥$",
            ),
            "♥ -",
            "♥-"
        ),
        "♥",
        CHAR(10)
    )
)
```

Comment: "all you need to do" lol. Some additional explanation here might be beneficial for other users.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones happy to add it for you if you wish so (?)

Comment: @player0 You didn't like my pretty printed version?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan tell me you are a programmer without telling me :)

Comment: @player0 I don't follow? Doesn't pretty printed version help folks who are not familiar with these advanced formulas?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan does it? I have no idea. I would incline to "no", but if it makes you happy I returned that "row monster" back